# clang-format-buffer with tramp doesn't actually format buffer

Tags: tramp, clang-format

I'm using Tramp to edit files on a remote machine, and when I run `clang-format-buffer`, it doesn't actually format the buffer. I get a message `(clang-format: success)` in the minibuffer, but the expected changes are not made in the buffer. If I use `clang-format-buffer` on a local copy of the file, it formats the file correctly.

What am I missing to get it to operate correctly on the buffer in Emacs using Tramp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which package you are using, but I guess it is `clang-format-20191121.1708` from MELPA. I've inspected the source code, and it uses `call-process-region` internally. `call-process` is agnostic to remote files, I suggest you contact the author of that package for supporting of remote files.